# Use TTF fonts from application's files dir in Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, font-face

I need to implement WebView which can render HTML offline. There are multiple fonts that might be used in HTML and I download all of them into app's files dir obtained with `context.getFilesDir()`.

My goal: "feed" these font files into WebView such that the rendered HTML looks correctly.

What I tried so far.

Bind HTML to WebView in the following manner:

```
baseUrl = "file:///data/user/0/com.myapp/files/fonts"; // this is for convenience, I don't hardcode like this in code
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

Specified folder contains all the donwloaded fonts.

And I also add `@font-face` configuration to HTML's header like this:

```
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
  <style id="fonts">@font-face { font-family: Guttman Stam; src: url(/Guttman Stam.ttf); }</style>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <p><span style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Guttman Stam;font-size:26pt;">text</span></p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I made sure that file `/data/user/0/com.myapp/files/fonts/Guttman Stam.ttf` exists.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I also tried to provide full paths in `@font-face` configuration while using both `null` and `""` as WebView's `baseUrl`, but no luck.

So, I'm kind of lost. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used this a long back not sure if this will work for your case , just use it for reference

```
 String finalDataToLoad = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/font_helvetica.css\"  />" + YOUR_HTML;

 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + outPutFolder, finalDataToLoad, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

the outPutFolder is where I had images

I had font in asset folder